# Making a Powershell script to open Programs and Features page in Control Panel

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I am writing my first PowerShell script. I am wanting it to open the control panel and uninstall/Change an app on my computer. I got it to open the control panel, but I don't know how to make it proceeded to the Programs and Features page. Once I do that how do I select and app? Say I want to select Google Chrome for example.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're probably best getting the uninstall strings for the applications you're interested in from the registry instead of trying to manipulate the control panel. Check this location for what you need: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: please take a look at an SO search for `[powershell] uninstall application` for many, many, many ideas. [*grin*]